# Go program works with the single channel and runs into a deadlock with the introduction of a new channel

Tags: go, deadlock

I am new to the go channels, I am trying to learn go channels by constructing a mock kernel and processes interaction through channels. The aim of this sample program is have multiple processes (2) sending *memory allocation requests* to the kernel using a *single channel* simultaneously, other processess sending *release memory requests* to the kernel using a *single but different channel*.

```
                                                      +-------------+
                           +------------------+       |             |
                          -> Alloc. Mem. Ch.  |<--\   |             |
+-----------------+   ---/ +------------------+   >-->|   Kernel    |
|   Process A     |<--     +------------------+ -/    |             |
+-----------------+   \--> |  Realse Mem. Ch. |<      |             |
                           +------------------+       +-------------+
```

Program works if I only have allocation requests, as soon as I introduces release requests program run into a deadlock.

Note, process also creates a reply queue when sending an allocation request however, that is not shown in the above diagram because it is not part of the problem.

The complete program is below:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        // "log"
        "time"
)

const (
        _ float64 = iota
        LowPrio
        MedPrio
        HghPrio
)

// Kernel type to communicate between processes and memory resources
type Kernel struct {
        reqMemCh chan chan int
        rlsMemCh chan int
}

func (k *Kernel) Init() {
        k.reqMemCh = make(chan chan int, 2)
        k.rlsMemCh = make(chan int, 2)
        go k.AllocMem()
        go k.RlsMem()
}

// Fetch memory on process request
func (k *Kernel) GetReqMemCh() chan chan int {
        return k.reqMemCh
}

func (k *Kernel) GetRlsMemCh() chan int {
        return k.rlsMemCh
}

func (k *Kernel) AllocMem() {
        // loop over the items (process reply channels) received over
        // the request channel
        for pCh := range k.GetReqMemCh() {
                // for now think 0 is the available index
                // send this as a reply to the exclusive process reply channel
                pCh <- 0
                close(pCh)
        }
}

// Release memory
func (k *Kernel) RlsMem() {
        // we do not have to anything here
}

// Process type which requests memory
type Proc struct {
        ind     int
        prio    float64
        exeT    time.Time
        count   int
        memInd  int
        rqMemCh chan chan int
        rlMemCh chan int
}

func (p *Proc) Init(
        ind int,
        prio float64,
        rqMemCh chan chan int,
        rlMemCh chan int,
) {
        p.ind = ind
        p.prio = prio
        p.memInd = -1
        p.rqMemCh = rqMemCh
        p.rlMemCh = rlMemCh
}

func (p *Proc) GetReqMemCh() chan chan int {
        return p.rqMemCh
}

func (p *Proc) GetRlsMemCh() chan int {
        return p.rlMemCh
}

func (p *Proc) ReqMem() {
        // create the reply channel exclusive to the process
        // this channel will return the allocated memeory id/address
        rpCh := make(chan int)
        // send the reply channel through the request channel
        // to get back the allocation memory id
        p.GetReqMemCh() <- rpCh
        // Below line is blocking ...
        for mi := range rpCh {
                p.memInd = mi
        }
}

func (p Proc) RlsMem() {
        p.GetRlsMemCh() <- 0
}

func (p Proc) String() string {
        return fmt.Sprintf(
                "Proc(%d): Memory(%d), Count(%d)",
                p.ind+1, p.memInd+1, p.count,
        )
}

func main() {

        k := &Kernel{}
        k.Init()

        p := &Proc{}
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
                p.Init(i, LowPrio, k.GetReqMemCh(), k.GetRlsMemCh())
                p.ReqMem()
                p.RlsMem()
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

and the exception is as follows:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.Proc.RlsMem(...)
        main.go:100
main.main()
        main.go:119 +0xc5

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
main.(*Kernel).AllocMem(0x0?)
        main.go:41 +0x5e
created by main.(*Kernel).Init in goroutine 1
        main.go:25 +0xc5
exit status 2
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Cheers,

DD.

Comment: As per [the language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Send_statements) "Communication blocks until the send can proceed". You have a channel (`k.rlsMemCh`) with a buffer that holds two requests to release memory, nothing ever reads from this channel. You attempt to send three values to the channel, so the third request will block. In `RlsMem()` you say `we do not have to anything here`; please explain this (at a minimum you need to read from `k.rlsMemCh`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Brits commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77596111/go-program-works-with-the-single-channel-and-runs-into-a-deadlock-with-the-intro#comment136797869_77596111), you have a buffered channel that is reaching it's capacity with nothing to read from it.

Per the language tour ([1](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2) [2](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/3)), sends and receives block until the other side is ready. While buffering a channel gives some lenience here, the behavior is the same once the buffer is full.

This can be fixed by adding a consumer for `k.rlsMemCh`. If you don't have any action planned for this, either remove the channel or have logic to drain it for now.

```golang
func (k *Kernel) Init() {
        k.reqMemCh = make(chan chan int, 2)
        k.rlsMemCh = make(chan int, 2)
        go k.AllocMem()
        go k.RlsMem()
}

func (k *Kernel) AllocMem() {
        for pCh := range k.GetReqMemCh() {
                pCh <- 0
                close(pCh)
        }
}

func (k *Kernel) RlsMem() {
        // TODO: Add a for-select or for-range over k.rlsMemCh here
}
```

Draining might look like this:

```
func (k *Kernel) RlsMem() {
        for {
                <-k.GetRlsMemCh()
        }
}
```